# Issue with GAN training in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, keras, generative-adversarial-network

I am trying to train a GAN for sequences but the following code is throwing error.

```
latent_dim  = 100
def generator():
  gen = Sequential([                  
                    Dense(25* 16, input_dim = latent_dim),
                    LeakyReLU(),
                    Dropout(0.2),
                    Reshape((25,16)),
                    Conv1DTranspose(32,3, 2, padding ="same"),
                    BatchNormalization(momentum = 0.7),
                    LeakyReLU(),
                    Dropout(0.2),
                    Conv1DTranspose(64,3, 2, padding ="same"),
                    BatchNormalization(momentum = 0.7),
                    LeakyReLU(),
                    Dropout(0.2),
                    Conv1D(96,3, 2, padding ="same"),
                    BatchNormalization(momentum = 0.7),
                    LeakyReLU(),
                    Dropout(0.2),
                    Dense(22, "softmax"),
                    Lambda(lambda x : tf.argmax(x, axis = -1)),                 
    ])
  print(gen.summary())
  return gen   

def descriminator():
  des = Sequential([
                    InputLayer(input_shape = (max_len, )),                  
                    Embedding(22, 100),
                    Conv1D(32,3, padding ="same"),
                    BatchNormalization(momentum = 0.7),
                    LeakyReLU(),
                    Conv1D(64,3, padding ="same"),
                    BatchNormalization(momentum = 0.7),
                    LeakyReLU(),
                    Conv1D(96,3, padding ="same"),
                    BatchNormalization(momentum = 0.7),
                    LeakyReLU(),
                    Flatten(),
                    Dense(100),
                    BatchNormalization(momentum = 0.7),
                    LeakyReLU(),
                    Dense(1, activation= "sigmoid")
    ]) 
  des.compile(tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.0003), "binary_crossentropy")
  print(des.summary())
  return des

def Adverserial(gen , des):
  des.trainable = False
  gan = Sequential()
  gan.add(gen)
  gan.add(des)
  gan.compile(tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.0003), "binary_crossentropy")
  return gan 

gen = generator()
des = descriminator() 
gan = Adverserial(gen, des)
```

The error is:

> ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: ['dense_44/kernel:0', 'dense_44/bias:0', 'conv1d_transpose_22/kernel:0', 'conv1d_transpose_22/bias:0', 'batch_normalization_77/gamma:0', 'batch_normalization_77/beta:0', 'conv1d_transpose_23/kernel:0', 'conv1d_transpose_23/bias:0', 'batch_normalization_78/gamma:0', 'batch_normalization_78/beta:0', 'conv1d_44/kernel:0', 'conv1d_44/bias:0', 'batch_normalization_79/gamma:0', 'batch_normalization_79/beta:0', 'dense_45/kernel:0', 'dense_45/bias:0'].

Is it because of the Lambda layer? If so how can I tackle that?

Comment: Where have you set `gen.compile`?

Comment: I am not sure if gen.compile is needed for gan training as gen will be trained through Gan network

Comment: What is max_len? And why is the output of your generator a single number?

Comment: max_len is the maximum length of the sequence that can be output for the generator network.

Comment: Try removing the `tf.argmax()` function wrapped in the `Lambda` layer and then run the code.

Comment: Argmax inside lambda layer is what making the generator's output consistent with the real data. Removing Lambda layer seems to work but doesn't serve my purpose. I want to know if there is anyway I can keep Lambda layer still make it work.